# Symfony Webpack Encore : Import .js from Bundle

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

With Symfony, I created a bundle. This bundle is correctly imported in `/vendor`.
This bundle have a two public files :

- `/MyBundle/Resources/Public/css/mybundle.scss`
- `/MyBundle/Resources/Public/js/mybundle.js`

How to import this files in my main projet with Wepack Encore ?

Currently i'm doing :

**In `assets/js/app.js` :**

> import "../../vendor/gaylordp/mybundle/Resources/public/js/mybundle.js";

**In `assets/css/app.scss` :**

> @import "../../vendor/gaylordp/mybundle/Resources/public/css/mybundle.scss";

But I think it's not ideal solution ... do you have other idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you have two solutions:

1. Do it like @hoover_D tells. Add two entries in your webpack.config.js.

   ```
   // for the js  
   .addEntry('js/mybundle', './vendor/.../mybundle.js')  

   // for the scss  
   .addStyleEntry('css/mybundle', './vendor/.../css/mybundle.scss')
   ```
2. If multiple files required the js code of your bundle, you can use the `createSharedEntry`. Documentation is [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/shared-entry.html).

   ```
   // for the js  
   .createSharedEntry('js/mybundle', './vendor/.../mybundle.js')  

   // for the scss  
   .addStyleEntry('css/mybundle', './vendor/.../css/mybundle.scss')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an entry in your `webpack.config.js`.

```
.addEntry('isotop', './vendor.../js/isotop.js')
```

after you do `yarn run dev` in the terminal to refresh the assets.

tell us if it works

Comment: Hum ... i'm sorry but I don't understand :/ My JS in my bundle (`/vendor/...`), not in assets

Comment: You can still use `addEntry` but use your `./vendor/...` path instead of `./assets/...`